# Ideals of non commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring.

(a) Show that there is a unique smallest (with respect to inclusion) ideal $A$ such that $R/A$
is a commutative ring.

(b) Give an example of a ring R such that for every proper ideal $I$, $R/I$ is not commutative.
Verify your example.

(c) For the ring $R = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix} | a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with the usual matrix operations, find the
ideal A of part (a).

(a) So this feels like a Zorn's lemma proof but instead of being able to consider an infinite ascending chain of Ideals and then showing their union is bounded above we would need to take an infinite descending chain of ideals. Its easy to show that the intersection of an infinite descending chain of ideals is an ideal but I am not sure how to prove that if I mod out by this intersection that I will have a commutative ring, and if so can Zorn's lemma be used to claim that this is the ideal?

If not I was thinking that if I take my infinite descending chain of ideals $A_1 > A_2 > ... $ then we have $R/A_1 < R/A_2 < ..$ is an infinite ascending chain of commutative rings so would it be better to apply Zorn's lemma to the $R/A_i$ instead of to the $A_i$?

(b) So I think that the idea is to take a non commutative ring $S$ an find a maximal ideal $M$ so that $S/M$ is commutative and and a proper Ideal $N$ containing $M$ and then set $R = S/N$. The only non commutative rings I know are matrix rings. But the problem is the set of upper triangular rings is a maximal ideal such that $S/M$ is commutative, but they are not properly contained in another ideal.

(c) I think the ideal  $I \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} | a \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ would work since the only ideals contained in $I$ are $\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & nZ \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \}$  and modding out by those ideals would not be commutative.

Comment: (a) If $R/I_1$ and $R/I_2$ are commutative, is $R/(I_1\cap I_2)$ commutative? (b) Why not take a simple ring?

Comment: An alternative approach to (a) is to note that if $R/A$ is commutative, then for every $x,y\in R$ you must have $xy-yx\in A$. So you may try to consider the ideal generated by such elements.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I think if $R/I_1$ and $R/I_2$ are commutative, than $R/(I_1\cap I_2)$ is commutative since if $R/I_l$ is commutative we have $a + b = b + a + i_1$ for some $i_1 \in I_1$, and  since if $R/I_2$ is commutative we have $a + b = b + a + i_2$ for some $i_2  \in I_2$ . Then $i_1 = i_2 \in I_1 \cap I_2$.

Comment: That solves (a).

Comment: Commutativity of a ring means $ab=ba$ for all $a$ and $b$. ($a+b=b+a$ is one of the axioms for rings.) Also, when applying Zorn's Lemma, note that it will give you a *minimal* ideal with the desired property; the question asks for a *smallest* such ideal.

Comment: @SamanthaWyler: Alternatively, you can map $R$ into $(R/I_1)\times(R/I_2)$, and the kernel of that map is $I_1\cap I_2$. If $R/I_1$ and $R/I_2$ are commutative, this embeds $R/(I_1\cap I_2)$ in a commutative ring.

Comment: @SamanthaWyler: Commutativity refers to multiplication, not addition. $a+b=b+a$ always holds. So your comment should be $ab=ba+i_1$ and $ab=ba+i_2$. Multiplication, not addition.

Comment: (b) You approach, as written does not really make much sense: if $M$ is maximal, then there is no proper ideal $N$ that contains $M$; and if $R/M$ is commutative (whether $M$ is maximal or not), and $N$ contains $M$, then $R/N$ is a quotient of $R/M$, and hence is also commutative.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I think it should also be noted the argument with intersections should be adapted for intersections of arbitrary families and not just pairwise intersections before unfurling the 'mission accomplished' banners.  There are things like this which can hold for finitely many intersections but not intersections of infinite families.  Luckily there is no problem proving the extended statement.